# how to open specific tcp port on ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, firewall

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, I am trying to run
`python -m http.server 8080`
and everything works, I can connect to the server from other computers
but if I change the port to:
`python -m http.server 8501`
I cannot connect to the server...

I tried disable `ufw` by `sudo ufw disable` to allow port 8501, does not work
I tried the `netstat` and it says the system is listen on `0.0.0.0:8501`
I tried `iptables` didn't find anything suspicious...

```
7    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:8501
8    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:8501
9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8501
10   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:8501
```

I was able to curl 127.0.0.1:8501 locally.

any particular setting that disallow this port to be accessible to external??

Comment: Did you restart your `http.server` after making these changes? Some settings are only recognized at server start. "... tried ufw. ... did not work" - details, please.

Comment: yeah, tried everything, restarted the server too

Comment: could it be that my company's internal network configuration disabled the port sharing for any traffic using the port? I just dont know if technically that is possible

Comment: Trying to violate your company's Security Policy (by getting around their TCP/IP Port rules) could get you fired, security clearance revoked, future job prospects reduced. Become aware of your company's Security Policy and don't violate it.

Comment: It could be that my company's intranet disables the port within the LAN. Although I cannot confirm this easily but if technically possible this could be the reason. I am not trying to violate the company's security policy, if not working i will stop.